# Drag div, place it correctly and send ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lot of things to do, but first thing first.

I have a `<div class="showcase">` containing a lot of `<div class="game">`, each of them having a

```
onclick="addpop('delpopup.php?id=something&pos=somethingelse&box=image')"
```

Tell me if this route is ok:

-use jQuery UI to manage the div drag (can I make the div "snap" in the right place? If i have div1, div2, div3 and div4, if i move div4 over div2, they have to place correctly in div1, div4, div2, div3 possibly not only graphically ("position:absolute") but also in html code

```
<div1>[...]</div>
<div4>[...]</div>
<div2>[...]</div>
<div3>[...]</div>
```

After each move, I have to change only the "pos" part of the addpop function of the right divs (if I move 4 over 2, i have to change div4 in pos2, div2 in pos3 and div3 in pos4)
(I think this part can be handled via javascript. Is that right?)

-After each drop, I'm sending a request via jQuery/Ajax to another page to try to change in the database the positions sending which DIV (pos and id) I moved and which DIV (pos and id) got the first over when I release the mouse button. How can I get those 4 datas (Can jQuery UI manage to get those datas for me?)

**(note: I'm NOT asking the solution of the whole problem; I'm asking if this is the right method to solve this problem)**

I was thinking about this possibility.
Or, there is another more-simple javascript/jquery/dunnowhat function that handle the whole thing alone?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `code onclick="addpop('delpopup.php?id=something&pos=somethingelse&box=image')" ` bad -> start by studying the jquery doc on drag & drop and set the callback they offer to do what you want to do http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Uhm, I'm going to take a look at the draggable+sortable part, that seems to work also on the html oderd part.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$(".div").droppable({ 
   drop: function( event, ui ) { 
      if (!ui.draggable.data("drop")){ 
         //here put your ajax
      } 
   }, 
   out: function( event, ui ) { 
      if (ui.draggable.data("soltado")){ 
        //logic of remove element
      } 
   } 
});
```

Example  [here](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/ejemplos/jquery/ui/interactions/9-droppable-azules-rojos.html)

Greetings.